# Responsive menu and using Javascripts to obtain width issues

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design

I am having an issue with the design of a responsive menu on an ipad mini, I am using javascript to detaect window size:

```
<p id="demo"></p>
<p id="demo1"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var x = "Total Width: " + screen.width + "px";
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;

    var y = "Total height: " + screen.height + "px";
    document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = y;

}
</script>
```

No matter the orientation, this is always:
Width:768
height:1024

Is there any other way of getting this value, across moile divices (mini and kindle) I am getting a difference in display. Anyone else had issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `window.innerWidth` and `window.innerHeight`instead. The `screen.width` and `screen.height` never change ...because they are the actual screen size ...but the the window does.

Comment: I would tend to agree with this. I'm working on a responsive design and I only use window.innerWidth.